# Is it okay start a sentence with a numeral?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it okay start a sentence with a numeral?

Style guides suggest otherwise.

> 7 a.m. is my favourite time to jog.

Comment: Write it out at the beginning of a sentence. Seven a.m. etc. But why not: My favorite time to jog is x.

Comment: Or, I usually go jogging at 7 a.m.

Comment: It is quite a commonly accepted style to definitely write numbers as words if they are smaller than a certain threshold, often 11, and optionally when larger for reasons of preference or if e.g. starting a sentence.

Comment: If you've been asked to follow a style guide, do what it says. A lot of these rules are a bit silly but you follow them because you have to, or because people will mark you down.

Comment: Says who? What style guide? Please [edit] your question to link to or give the name of the style guide